# Retrieve value from WSDL using SOAP - PHP

Tags: php, soap, wsdl

I have a very poor, in structure, WSDL file and I can't understand how I can retrieve information from it.

> VM is not accessible from an outside network so I can't share the whole WSDL file

I would like to use `getList` function that takes an argument and returns a string, with multiple values.

```
SOAP Request

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <S:Header/>
    <S:Body>
        <ns2:getList xmlns:ns2="http://Wishlist.eBookCafe/">
            <arg0>2</arg0>
        </ns2:getList>
    </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>

SOAP Response

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <S:Body>
        <ns2:getListResponse xmlns:ns2="http://Wishlist.eBookCafe/">
            <return>[1]</return>
        </ns2:getListResponse>
    </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

My question is, because value is included inside `return` tag, I don't know how I can store it in a PHP variable using SOAP.

```
$list = $service->getList(array('arg0'=>$id));
print_r($list);
```

Even if I am using static numbers as passing arguments it always returns the values that contained to the user with id = 1.

Answer (score 0):

From a blog post (which is **removed now** :( ) >>

```
<?php
$url = 'your_url_orFilePath';
$client = new SoapClient($url);

$xmlr = new SimpleXMLElement("<main_key></main_key>");
$xmlr->addChild('childName1', $childName1);
$xmlr->addChild('childName2', $childName2);
------
----likewise---

$params = new stdClass();
$params->xml = $xmlr->asXML();
$result = $client->main_key_function($params);
?>
```